# Computing Moore-Penrose generalized inverse using convergent geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrix-equations, matrix-inverse

I came across an article (published in IEEE transactions or Wiley publications) which states that moore-penrose generalized inverse can be computed using the following two  equations.

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. $A^{*}$ is its hermitian conjugate, and $0 < \alpha < c$, where $c$ = max eigenvalue ($A^{*}A$). The convergence of following two equations is assured,

$A^{+} = \alpha \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(I_{m}-\alpha A^{*}A)^{k} A^{*}$

$A^{+} = \alpha \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A^{*}(I_{n}-\alpha AA^{*})^{k}$

Through simulations this seems to be true. Can somebody prove that the series is always convergent?

Edit 1: Reference link (Check theorem 16) http://benisrael.net/BI-CHARNES-GI-SIAM-1963.pdf.

Is it right if we can say that $(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}1) 0 = 0$? (As per the assumption in the reference)

Comment: Could be helpful to have a reference to the article.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#The_iterative_method_of_Ben-Israel_and_Cohen) mentions the iterative method of Ben-Israel and Cohen which seems to be related to this. It starts with $A_0=\alpha A^*$ and goes with $A_{n+1}=2A_n-A_nAA_n$.

Comment: I've posted the reference. Check theorem 16, in the proof.

Comment: I don't see whether their restriction on $\alpha$ ($<2/|d_i|^2$ where $d_i$ are entries of the SVD middle diagonal)  is equivalent to yours. Maybe the explanation lies there?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The condition is not equivalent, just look at 1x1 matrices. In fact the condition $\alpha<2/d_i^2$ is exactly what is needed to force the eigenvalues of $I-\alpha A^\ast A$ to have absolute value less than 1 which is exactly what is needed to make to geometric series convergent.